# How to display a Yes/No style message box in web part, and get client's choice?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I want to show a message box when users trying to do any major operations in my web part. If user choince [Yes], then continue to do sometiing ...[No] for nothing.

How can i implements this function in my web part , Sharepoint 2007 ??

pls help me ~~

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using an ASP.Net control like a Button, you can add the following attribute to give the user a JavaScript popup before the postback actually happens:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');" />
```

You can also set this property on the button object in your code:

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to do this?');";
```